# Calculate at what row will UITableView stop scrolling?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, gesture

When a table has many rows, the user can flick up/down the table. This creates a scrolling animation which seems to have a deterministic length depending on the speed/length of the flick gesture. Is it possible to reliably calculate what rows in the table will be visible once the scrolling stops if there is no further user interaction?

Comment: Good question, but as far as I've been able to tell..no, that seems like it would be something of a complex operation to keep around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 5.0 and later there is a new API for the [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) called [scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging%3awithVelocity%3atargetContentOffset%3a). With this new method the stop position of the scroll can be calculated and even modified, as explained in the [Video Session 100: What's New in Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), around the ninth minute.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` and you can accomplish that by using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods and the table view `indexPathsForVisibleRows` property to check which cell index paths are visible at the moment the scrolling stops.

You can even save the initial position from where the deceleration started, so that you can calculate whether the scroll direction was up or down, which will then let you know if is the cell that it will stop is the first or the last of the visible ones.

```
int startDeceleratingPosition;

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    startDeceleratingPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    BOOL isPositionUp = startDeceleratingPosition < scrollView.contentOffset.y;     

    NSArray *paths = [_myTableview indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(isPositionUp){
        cell = [_myTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    } else {
        cell = [_myTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[paths lastObject]];
    }

}
```

An important note about the code above is that it points to the table view as a variable `_myTableview` instead of just casting the delegate method variable `scrollView` to a `UITableView *`, although that is just implementation details and should not affect the logic here.

Comment: But there is such a way... UIScrollView has a decelerationRate property, which would just be a low level approach for that, and also with a lot more chances to get a wrong result. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: The deceleration rate is just a constant, like gravity. You need to know the current scrolling speed in order to make further calculations as to when and where the scrolling will stop, and I don't see any way to get the speed of the scrolling through public API.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question..... `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` as well: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate

There are some delegate callbacks you could use to know when the scrolling begins to decelerate, and ends decelerating.

You could probably use `– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`and at that point use the cell heights and the content offset property of the tableView (tableView subclasses `UIScrollView`) and then calculate the cells that are visible after deceleration.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how you could determine how many rows WILL show, but you can always get how many rows HAVE shown. (once the table stops w/no further touching.)
Not sure if that helps but this is how you would do it

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    // make sure to declare your integer in your .h file and to also synthesize
    //say this is your int "howManyRowsAreShowing"
    howManyRowsAreShowing = indexPath.Row;



    //the rest of the code below is generic table view code for example only
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
    }
```